# Is there a way to get over 4 arguments in GUI.Label() in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a scoring system and I want to change the font size and color. I can only do one because I keep getting the error:

> No overload for method 'Label' takes 4 arguments.

Is there a way I can put both of those in?

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void OnGUI()
{
    
    GUIStyle s = new GUIStyle();
    s.fontSize = 30;
    GUI.contentColor = Color.red;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 100), "Score: " + points, s, "color");
}
```

Comment: What do you want/expect it to do with the string `"color"`?

Comment: General hint regarding c# .. or any language .. if some method takes in a certain amount of arguments .. then no, you can't simply pass in a different amount. All you can do is look out for overloads that maybe take different arguments that serve your purpose

Comment: In general the IMGUI system is quite legacy and only really used for editor scripting .. you should rather use the uGUI system (`UnityEngine.UI`) or UIToolkit (`UnityEngune.UIElements`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below overload

```
public static void Label(Rect position, string text, GUIStyle style);
```

Pass the font and color through `GUIStyle`

We can set many attributes. Refer below documentation link.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.html

Rough code here:

```
GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();
myStyle.fontSize = 30;
myStyle.normal.textColor = Color.red;
```

So the call roughly looks like

```
 GUI.Label(new Rect(0, 0, 300, 100), "Score: " + points, myStyle);
```